# Unpermitted parameters: error after whitelisting params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting a "Unpermitted Parameters: :event_id, :attendee_id" even though I'm whitelisting the params

```
Started POST "/planned_events" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-22 22:08:39 +0900
Processing by PlannedEventsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     
"authenticity_token"=>"WhVcJWjo08KWqxFViUPbSZVMYzu2UgGW9E+WRExP9Wc=", "planned_event"=>      
{":event_id"=>"3", ":attendee_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Attend"}
Unpermitted parameters: :event_id, :attendee_id
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "planned_events" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)      
[["created_at", Fri, 22 Aug 2014 13:08:39 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Fri, 22 Aug 2014  
13:08:39 UTC +00:00]]
(1.8ms)  commit transaction
Unpermitted parameters: :event_id, :attendee_id
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms

ActionController::UrlGenerationError (No route matches {:action=>"show",     
:controller=>"events", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]):
app/controllers/planned_events_controller.rb:6:in `create'
```

Here is controllers/planned_events_controller.rb

```
class PlannedEventsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @planned_event = PlannedEvent.new(planned_event_params)
    if @planned_event.save
        redirect_to event_path(planned_event_params[:event_id])
    end
end

def destroy
    @planned_event = PlannedEvent.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to event_path(planned_event_params[:event_id] => :id)
end

private

    def planned_event_params
        params.require(:planned_event).permit(:event_id, :attendee_id)
    end
end
```

Why?

The broswer is highlighting the "redirect_to..." line with the error.

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in PlannedEventsController#create
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events", :id=>nil} missing required keys:    
[:id]
```

I assume the :id is nil because it wont accept the id i'm passing it (from the whitelisted params), and can't find an alternative.

Comment: Can you post your `model` and `form code`?

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters have wrong names:

```
{":event_id"=>"3", ":attendee_id"=>"1"}
```

Change them in your form, incoming parameters should be

```
{"event_id"=>"3", "attendee_id"=>"1"}
```

Also, you can change whole redirect_to to shorter version:

```
redirect_to @planned_event.event
```

Answer (score 0):

**its a routes error**.instead of moving to `create` its moving to `show` action of controller.

**remember:-**

```
your create link should be post
your show action should be get(with id passed)
```

i think your view needs to be looked upon where you are clicking.check the `link_to` or `submit button` or your `form_for`

Comment: Its moving to create, then redirecting_to show. Marcin's answer fixed the problem, it was a :user_id vs user_id issue

Comment: Mark it as an answer if you say so :)